# Pandas dataframe applymap parallel execution

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I have the following functions to apply bunch of regexes to each element in a data frame. The dataframe that I am applying the regexes to is a 5MB chunk.

```
def apply_all_regexes(data, regexes):
    # find all regex matches is applied to the pandas' dataframe
    new_df = data.applymap(
        partial(apply_re_to_cell, regexes))
    return regex_applied

def apply_re_to_cell(regexes, cell):
    cell = str(cell)
    regex_matches = []
    for regex in regexes:
        regex_matches.extend(re.findall(regex, cell))
    return regex_matches
```

Due to the serial execution of `applymap`, the time taken to process is  ~ `elements * (serial execution of the regexes for 1 element)`. Is there anyway to invoke parallelism? I tried `ProcessPoolExecutor`, but that appeared to take longer time than executing serially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried splitting your one big dataframe in number of threads small dataframes, apply the regex map parallel and stick each small df back together?

I was able to do something similar with a dataframe about gene expression.
I would run it small scale and control if you get the expected output.

Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to comment

```
def parallelize_dataframe(df, func):
    df_split = np.array_split(df, num_partitions)
    pool = Pool(num_cores)
    for x in df_split:
        print(x.shape)
    df = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


    return df
```

This is the general function I used

Comment: Good point. I did the split on not the dataframe but trying to parallelly execute the tasks by regexes.

Comment: I wasn't able to speed up the process with it. If you find a way please let me know. Splitting the dataframe was kinda a hassle

Comment: the execution did speed up. Need to do some tweaking with `num_partitions` and `num_cores`. In my case, I kept both of them constant to match the number of cores running. Saw ~50% reduction.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more modern version:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

tqdm.pandas()

def parallel_applymap(df, func, worker_count):
    def _apply(shard):
        return shard.progress_applymap(func)

    shards = np.array_split(df, worker_count)
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=worker_count) as e:
        futures = e.map(_apply, shards)
    return pd.concat(list(futures))
```